# Compare file sizes in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm trying to compare the size of two files in shell script but I'm getting a **test: 32: 8: unexpected operator** error.

```
I=`wc -c $i | cut -d' ' -f1`
J=`wc -c $j | cut -d' ' -f1`
if test $I == $J
then
      echo $i $j >> $1.pares
fi
```

I test the values in $I and $J using echo and the values are correct but I cant compare them...

Comment: IIRC, `==` is a bash extension and is used in bash numeric expressions: `(( $I == $J ))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using square braces (`[]`) and `-eq` like so:

```
I=`wc -c $i | cut -d' ' -f1`
J=`wc -c $j | cut -d' ' -f1`
if [ $I -eq $J ]
then
      echo $i $j >> $1.pares
fi
```

Comment: Try `-eq` instead of `==`: `if [ $I -eq $J ]; then...`

Comment: I just tried = instead of == and it worked, and -eq also worked

Answer (score 14):

this works on bash

```
if((`stat -c%s "$file1"`==`stat -c%s "$file2"`));then
  echo "do something"
fi
```

Comment: On a Mac, this returns `stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]`

Comment: @LOlliffe if I am not wrong, change -c to -f, the problem is that on linux -f means --file-system. Feel free to add a mac alternative after you make it work, by editing my answer if you prefer :)

Comment: @AquariusPower `stat -f file.ext` just prints the file name `fiel.ext` on macOS. To get the file size in bytes on macOS use `stat -f%z file.ext`.

Comment: These days (2021) I see `$()` is recommended as preferred to backquote, since it's easy to see the closing delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
I=`wc -c "$i"` # always use quoted var
J=`wc -c "$j"`
[[ "$I" == "$J" ]] && echo "$i" "$j" >> "$1".pares
```

Always quote variables, because you can have a file name containing a space.

Despite BASH is case insensitive with variable names, it's better and safer to use different (and longer than one char) name for variables.

Comment: If all you want is the filesize, avoid using `cat foobar | wc -c`, because it will read the entire file from the disk (or from a remote location, or from wherever). It is just a waste of time for larger files. Prefer using `wc -c foobar`.

Comment: Yeah, that is true :) I know this now, but didnt know this when I write the answer. Will fix it

Comment: In case you're wondering, this reasonable optimisation of `wc` has existed since at least its initial commit to coreutils in 1992: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/b25038ce9a234ea0906ddcbd8a0012e917e6c661/src/wc.c#L157

Comment: I would prefer `stat -c '%s'` to get a file's size. `wc` is a good to count lines though.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work....

```
#/bin/bash <br>
I=`wc -c < echo $i`
J=`wc -c < echo $j`

if [ $I -eq $J ]; then

 echo $i $j >> $1.pares

fi
```

Hugs!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please translate the opening sentence into English, and try to explain why it works (and why the code in the question did not work).